# Get the Application Downloaded and active device statistics in google play

Tags: android, google-play, usage-statistics

i can get the Comments of my app in google play store using the An open-source API for the Android Market .
http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

but i need the Device Active Installs and Apps Downloaded Statistics for my app in google Play ? is there any API available for that.

Thanks
Sangeeth

Answer (score 1):

No there is no API. But you can check the sources of Andlytics: https://github.com/AndlyticsProject/andlytics or use app directly.

Comment: Again - there's no offcial Google API for this.